# How do I send several commands to the same cmd instance in perl?

Tags: windows, perl, winapi, cmd, win32gui

My problem is that I need to build a script that will send commands to the single win32 CMD instance. 
The `"system @cmd"` or ``` "`` @cmd" ``` won't help here, since they always create a new instance. 
It should look like this in pseudo code:

```
my $consoleWindow = CreateConsole;

my $cmdargs1 = "foo";
my $cmdargs2 = "bar";

Send($cmdargs1, $consoleWindow);
sleep(1);
Send($cmdargs2, $consoleWindow); #send to the same instance
```

I believe, that I would have to create new cmd window, hook to it and then send my commands to it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In principle what you need to do is run cmd.exe with its standard handles redirected to pipes. Write commands to stdin and read from stdout and stderr, preferably using threads to avoid a deadlock.

Comment: BTW, can you elaborate why it is that you need a single instance of cmd?

Comment: This is how GPUView in [Windows SDK works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/using-gpuview) 
One have to send `log.cmd` to the single cmd instance, otherwise logging won't stop

Comment: Have you tried a command sequence like `"foo & bar"`?

Comment: not really.. can you explain? I also need to have timeout between calling log.cmd (start logging, wait 10 sec, stop logging)

Comment: For example, run the following in a command prompt: `cmd /c "echo spam & (timeout 10 > nul) & echo eggs"`.

Comment: @eryksun Could you make that an answer please?

Comment: Running `cmd /c "log.cmd & (timeout 10 > nul) & log.cmd` directly in command promt works perfectly fine, it really launches log.cmd. 
But when I do this using perl, it will just output "log.cmd" two times and do nothing, is there a way to recognize it as a command not plain text? (removing echo was actually doing this in cmd, but not using perl)

Comment: I had `cmd /c` in the example because that's typically what a language's `system` function executes. Just use `"log.cmd & (timeout 10 > nul) & log.cmd"` for the argument to such a function.

Comment: Yeah, that works totally fine! Thanks a lot!